# Handsontable afterSelectionEnd not work with dropdown

Tags: handsontable, dropdown

I've four columns, the last two are dropdowns. When I change the row in the last dropdown (I changed the code, when Enter key is pressed, it moves to the next column, if it is in the last column, it moves to next row), I try to fetch row data with getDataAtRow, but the last value don't appear in this event.
I need this to do an insert in my db, but the last value is null (nullable=false in my db).